# How to update internal data using use_data

Tags: r, r-usethis

I would like my script to access internal data that can be updated.  The data will be countries visited and the date.  Not a high frequency data set, so doesn't justify using a database.

These are the lines I tried:

```
country_vis <- bind_rows(country_vis, c(country = new_country, date = entry_date))
usethis::use_data(country_vis, internal = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE, version = 3)
```

the bind_rows is fine, but the data is not updated.

1. Do I have to rebuild the package or reference an environment?
   or,
2. Is this not a legitimate use of `use_data`? What would be the better way?

Comment: Tell us about the package or project you're writing. Is it local-only, do you host it as a git repo for personal use? Is it installable by others? Is it "served" anywhere, such as shiny/plumber/dash/...?

Comment: This is a local-only project.  I need to keep a local list of countries and the dates they were visited, so that I can fill a map and calculate the percentage of the world's landmass visited.  If successful, I'll make it a downloadable package.

Comment: I got the idea from maps, where you can scratch off the countries visited.

Comment: Not sure, but ... fyi: `bind_rows(country_vis, c(...))` is a bad way to do that: if `new_country` is (say) `character` and `date` is class `Date`, then ... `date` will be coerced to `character` by the call to `c`. Use `list(country=new_country, date=entry_date)` instead, the classes of the inner objects it not altered.